# Xarray (from grib file) to dataset

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray, grib, cfgrib

I have a grib file containing monthly precipitation and temperature from 1989 to 2018 (extracted from ERA5-Land).

I need to have those data in a dataset format with 6 column : longitude, latitude, ID of the cell/point in the grib file, date, temperature and precipitation.

I first imported the file using cfgrib. Here is what contains the xdata list after importation:

```
import cfgrib

grib_data = cfgrib.open_datasets('\era5land_extract.grib')

grib_data
Out[6]: 
[<xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:     (latitude: 781, longitude: 761, time: 372)
 Coordinates:
     number      int32 0
   * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1989-01-01 1989-02-01 ... 2019-12-01
     step        timedelta64[ns] 1 days
     surface     float64 0.0
   * latitude    (latitude) float64 42.0 41.9 41.8 41.7 ... -35.8 -35.9 -36.0
   * longitude   (longitude) float64 -21.0 -20.9 -20.8 -20.7 ... 54.8 54.9 55.0
     valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] ...
 Data variables:
     t2m         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
 Attributes:
     GRIB_edition:            1
     GRIB_centre:             ecmf
     GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
     GRIB_subCentre:          0
     Conventions:             CF-1.7
     institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts,
 <xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:     (latitude: 781, longitude: 761, time: 156)
 Coordinates:
     number      int32 0
   * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1989-01-01 1989-02-01 ... 2001-12-01
     step        timedelta64[ns] 1 days
     surface     float64 0.0
   * latitude    (latitude) float64 42.0 41.9 41.8 41.7 ... -35.8 -35.9 -36.0
   * longitude   (longitude) float64 -21.0 -20.9 -20.8 -20.7 ... 54.8 54.9 55.0
     valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] ...
 Data variables:
     tp          (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
 Attributes:
     GRIB_edition:            1
     GRIB_centre:             ecmf
     GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
     GRIB_subCentre:          0
     Conventions:             CF-1.7
     institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts,
 <xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:     (latitude: 781, longitude: 761, time: 216)
 Coordinates:
     number      int32 0
   * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-01-01 2002-02-01 ... 2019-12-01
     step        timedelta64[ns] 1 days
     surface     float64 0.0
   * latitude    (latitude) float64 42.0 41.9 41.8 41.7 ... -35.8 -35.9 -36.0
   * longitude   (longitude) float64 -21.0 -20.9 -20.8 -20.7 ... 54.8 54.9 55.0
     valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] ...
 Data variables:
     tp          (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
 Attributes:
     GRIB_edition:            1
     GRIB_centre:             ecmf
     GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
     GRIB_subCentre:          0
     Conventions:             CF-1.7
     institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts]
```

So the temperature variable is called "t2m" and the precipitation variable "tp".
Temperature variable is split in two xarrays but I don't understand why.

How can I obtain the needed dataset from this please ?

It's the first time I'm dealing with such data, and I'm really lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you try to use `merge` to combine the three into a single dataset? Perhaps you should start merging the two `tp` on the time dimension. Then, once you have a single dataset, you can try to export it in a tabular format. However, be aware that the resulting dataset will have more than 200 million rows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer after a bit of trial and error (only putting the result for tp variable but it's similar for t2m)

```
import cfgrib
import xarray as xr


# Import data
grib_data = cfgrib.open_datasets('\era5land_extract.grib')


# Merge both tp arrays into one on the time dimension
grib_precip = xr.merge([grib_data[1], grib_data[2]])


# Aggregate data by year
grib_precip_year = grib_precip.resample(time="Y", skipna=True).mean()


# Data from xarray to pandas
grib_precip_pd = grib_precip_year.to_dataframe()
```

Comment: what happens if you do `ds = xr.open_dataset("era5land_extract.grib", engine="cfgrib")`?

Comment: I would do the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you end up with two `xarray.Datasets` is because the two variables are mapped to different "hypercubes". You can open only one at a time using the `backend_kwargs = {'typeOfLevel': <level>}` syntax. See the docss for `cfgrib` [here](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib#filter-heterogeneous-grib-files). You may want to use `cfgrib.open_datasets` but you can pass `backend_kwargs` as kwargs to xarray methods, too.

It is sometimes possible to merge variables from two hypercubes, as you seem to have found. In more complex situations, for example when there are data_vars with the same name on more than one hypercube, you will have to do some manual intervention to be able to combine the datasets.